# Easy fancybox and Contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, fancybox, contact-form

Right now I am working on a contact form. I decided to use Easy Fancybox, and Contact Form7,
but I cannot get it work. I inserted it all here:

```
<div class="bottom-nav navbar-fixed-bottom">
 <p class="bottom-nav-p" title="">© Kaduilla, 2014. <a class="fancybox" href="#fancybox-auto">Ota Yhteyttä</a><div style="display:none"></p>
<div id="contact_form_pop">
 <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1328" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>   
</div>
</div>
```

The Easy Fancybox is opened when the #fancybox-auto is clicked.
It reacts, and shows as if it was loading.
,but nothing happens.
Hope to get some help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the easy fancybox fires on the class '.fancybox', then we can assume that the code should be:

```
<div class="bottom-nav navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p class="bottom-nav-p" title="">
        © Kaduilla, 2014. <a class="fancybox" href="#contact_form_pop">Ota Yhteyttä</a>
    </p>
    <div id="contact_form_pop" style="display:none">
       <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1328" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>   
    </div>
</div>
```

If the class is used to trigger the link to open the fancybox, then how does it know what div to target and open? That would typically be the href value, just an ID selector for the ID of the div you want to open.

**The HREF on the link used to open the fancybox is how the fancybox knows what HTML content to open. This should target the div you're trying to display.**

Comment: Thank you!This works, but partly, now it tells me that there was an error in loading the content